# Creating a multi-column table with dynamically wide columns from a CSV file

Tags: tables, csv

I'm trying to make a multi-column table take dynamic values, read from a CSV file. The current table looks like this and has been formatted manually with `tabularx`, without any multicolumn package whatsoever.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l l X|l l X|}
    \hline
    name1 & nr1 & & name4 & nr4 & \\
    name2 & nr2 & & name5 & nr5 & \\
    name3 & nr3 & & name6 & nr6 & \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

[image: how it is supposed to look]

It is important that the third and sixth column are empty and as large as possible while being the same size; the table is supposed to span over the whole width of the page.

I've tried multiple approaches to dynamically create this table from a CSV file, but I never even came close to reproducing what I was able to create statically. Here is an example approach using the `datatool` package in combination with `multicol`, which probably came closest to what I wanted to achieve, albeit still being miles away:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{lmodern,datatool,tabularx,multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Name,Number
name1,nr1
name2,nr2
name3,nr3
name4,nr4
name5,nr5
name6,nr6
name7,nr7
name8,nr8
name9,nr9
name10,nr10
name11,nr11
name12,nr12
name13,nr13
name14,nr14
name15,nr15
name16,nr16
name17,nr17
name18,nr18
name19,nr19
name20,nr20
name21,nr21
name22,nr22
name23,nr23
name24,nr24
name25,nr25
name26,nr26
name27,nr27
name28,nr28
name29,nr29
name30,nr30
name31,nr31
name32,nr32
name33,nr33
name34,nr34
name35,nr35
name36,nr36
name37,nr37
name38,nr38
name39,nr39
name40,nr40
name41,nr41
name42,nr42
name43,nr43
name44,nr44
name45,nr45
name46,nr46
name47,nr47
name48,nr48
name49,nr49
name50,nr50
name51,nr51
name52,nr52
name53,nr53
name54,nr54
name55,nr55
name56,nr56
name57,nr57
name58,nr58
name59,nr59
name60,nr60
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \DTLloaddb{Data}{data.csv}
    \noindent
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|l l X|}
            \hline
            \DTLforeach*{Data}{\Name=Name,\Number=Number}{
                \Name & \Number & \\
            }
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: The end result]

As the end result is obviously nowhere near what it was supposed to look, I looked for alternatives and found the `csvsimple` package, but I also can't get that to work in combination with `tabularx`. If anyone could help me wrap my head around on what is wrong here and what to fix it, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: your tabular is long you need longtable but longtable don't go with multicol

Comment: So your problem is already related to making a table wrap over the page boundary? Or will that never happen?

Comment: ...and, are the borders necessary?

Comment: The data set is small enough so that the table should never reach the end of the page, but two columns are a must. I'd also consider the borders necessary, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are prepared to use `pgfplotstable` then this can be done.  It contains a construct to divide columns in to equal parts to simulate multicolumn tables, namely `select equal part entry of`.  Dividing in to two columns is achieved with the first column being given style `select equal part entry of={0}{2}` and the second `select equal part entry of={1}{2}`.

You set up a `tabularx` output with the options

```
 begin table=\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth},
 end table=\end{tabularx}
```

to `\pgfplotstabletypeset`,
and then the combination

```
  columns={Name,Number,XXX,Name,Number,XXX},
  display columns/0/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{2},column type=|c},
  display columns/1/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{2}},
  display columns/2/.style={column type=X|},
  display columns/3/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{2},column type=c},
  display columns/4/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{2}},
  display columns/5/.style={column type=X|}
```

provides the divided columns with the appropriate formatting.  The empty `XXX` columns are generated by

```
create on use/XXX/.style={create col/set={}}
```

You need to specify your data as being comma separated and of string type via

```
col sep=comma,string type
```

Finally in the example below I have thrown away the headers and added horizontal rules corresponding to your question.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern,pgfplotstable,tabularx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Name,Number
name1,nr1
name2,nr2
name3,nr3
name4,nr4
name5,nr5
name6,nr6
name7,nr7
name8,nr8
name9,nr9
name10,nr10
name11,nr11
name12,nr12
name13,nr13
name14,nr14
name15,nr15
name16,nr16
name17,nr17
name18,nr18
name19,nr19
name20,nr20
name21,nr21
name22,nr22
name23,nr23
name24,nr24
name25,nr25
name26,nr26
name27,nr27
name28,nr28
name29,nr29
name30,nr30
name31,nr31
name32,nr32
name33,nr33
name34,nr34
name35,nr35
name36,nr36
name37,nr37
name38,nr38
name39,nr39
name40,nr40
name41,nr41
name42,nr42
name43,nr43
name44,nr44
name45,nr45
name46,nr46
name47,nr47
name48,nr48
name49,nr49
name50,nr50
name51,nr51
name52,nr52
name53,nr53
name54,nr54
name55,nr55
name56,nr56
name57,nr57
name58,nr58
name59,nr59
name60,nr60
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{create on use/XXX/.style={create col/set={}}}%
\noindent
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,string type,
  begin table=\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth},
  end table=\end{tabularx},
  every head row/.style={output empty row,after row=\hline},
  every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
  columns={Name,Number,XXX,Name,Number,XXX},
  display columns/0/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{2},column type=|c},
  display columns/1/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{2}},
  display columns/2/.style={column type=X|},
  display columns/3/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{2},column type=c},
  display columns/4/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{2}},
  display columns/5/.style={column type=X|}
]{data.csv}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not what you looking for but maybe it help

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{lmodern,datatool,tabularx,multicol,ifthen}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Name,Number
name1,nr1
name2,nr2
name3,nr3
name4,nr4
name5,nr5
name6,nr6
name7,nr7
name8,nr8
name9,nr9
name10,nr10
name11,nr11
name12,nr12
name13,nr13
name14,nr14
name15,nr15
name16,nr16
name17,nr17
name18,nr18
name19,nr19
name20,nr20
name21,nr21
name22,nr22
name23,nr23
name24,nr24
name25,nr25
name26,nr26
name27,nr27
name28,nr28
name29,nr29
name30,nr30
name31,nr31
name32,nr32
name33,nr33
name34,nr34
name35,nr35
name36,nr36
name37,nr37
name38,nr38
name39,nr39
name40,nr40
name41,nr41
name42,nr42
name43,nr43
name44,nr44
name45,nr45
name46,nr46
name47,nr47
name48,nr48
name49,nr49
name50,nr50
name51,nr51
name52,nr52
name53,nr53
name54,nr54
name55,nr55
name56,nr56
name57,nr57
name58,nr58
name59,nr59
name60,nr60
\end{filecontents*}

\def\mtodd{\Name & \Number & &}
\def\mteven{\mtevenL \\}
\def\mtoddL{\mtodd & & }
\def\mtevenL{\Name & \Number & }

\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb{Data}{data.csv}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l l X|l l X|}
\hline
\DTLforeach*{Data}{\Name=Name,\Number=Number}{%
\DTLifoddrow{\DTLiflastrow{\mtoddL}{\mtodd}}{%
\DTLiflastrow{\mtevenL}{\mteven}}}
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Update:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{lmodern,datatool,tabularx,multicol,ifthen}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Name,Number
name1,nr1
name2,nr2
name3,nr3
name4,nr4
name5,nr5
name6,nr6
name7,nr7
name8,nr8
name9,nr9
name10,nr10
name11,nr11
name12,nr12
name13,nr13
name14,nr14
name15,nr15
name16,nr16
name17,nr17
name18,nr18
name19,nr19
name20,nr20
name21,nr21
name22,nr22
name23,nr23
name24,nr24
name25,nr25
name26,nr26
name27,nr27
name28,nr28
name29,nr29
name30,nr30
name31,nr31
name32,nr32
name33,nr33
name34,nr34
name35,nr35
name36,nr36
name37,nr37
name38,nr38
name39,nr39
name40,nr40
name41,nr41
name42,nr42
name43,nr43
name44,nr44
name45,nr45
name46,nr46
name47,nr47
name48,nr48
name49,nr49
name50,nr50
name51,nr51
name52,nr52
name53,nr53
name54,nr54
name55,nr55
name56,nr56
name57,nr57
name58,nr58
name59,nr59
name60,nr60
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb{Data}{data.csv}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l l X|l l X|}
\hline
\DTLforeach*{Data}{\Name=Name,\Number=Number}{%
\DTLiffirstrow{}{\DTLifoddrow{\\}{&}}%
\Name & \Number &}%
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```