# Appending Graphic from Optional CSV Column to PGFPlotsTable Column Content

Tags: tables, graphics, pgfplotstable, csv

I have a CSV file containing a list of names, numbers and optionally pictures. This file is to be displayed in a multi-column table, with the name (and optionally appended picture as icon) in one column, the number in another and a free column in the third. It's important that the picture/icon is appended directly to the name and is not in a separate column.

In order to accomplish this, I have tried combining [the answer to an earlier question of mine regarding dynamic multi-column tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231393/24604) and [this answer about post-processing columns using other values from the CSV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180109/24604), but am unable to produce the desired result; here is my attempt as an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{extarticle}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,top=2cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
        
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    Name,Number,Picture
    name1,1,
    name2,2,
    name3,3,ex1.png
    name4,4,
    name5,5,
    name6,6,
    name7,7,
    name8,8,
    name9,9,ex2.png
    name10,10,
    name11,11,
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\datatable}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableset{create on use/XXX/.style={create col/set={}}}%
    
    \noindent
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
    begin table=\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth},
        end table=\end{tabularx},
    every head row/.style={output empty row,after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    columns={Name,Number,XXX,Name,Number,XXX},
    display columns/0/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{2},column type=|l,postproc cell content/.add code={%
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Picture}\of\datatable%
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{%
                \noexpand%
                \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}%
                ~\pgfplotsretval%
                %~\includegraphics[height=\lineheight]{\pgfplotsretval}%
            }%
        }%
    },
    display columns/1/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{2}},
    display columns/2/.style={column type=X|},
    display columns/3/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{2},column type=l,postproc cell content/.add code={%
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Picture}\of\datatable%
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{%
                \noexpand%
                \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}%
                ~\pgfplotsretval%
                %~\includegraphics[height=\lineheight]{\pgfplotsretval}%
            }%
        }%
    },
    display columns/4/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{2}},
    display columns/5/.style={column type=X|}
    ]{\datatable}
\end{document}
```

If one uncomments the `\includegraphics` statements, the code doesn't even compile. I'd guess a check is needed on whether there is data in the Picture column for the current row; and apart from that, the current content needs to be fetched reliably, as what I've currently got always grabs `"datatable` as content, although it at least compiles.

I've tried approaching this multiple times already, but even with help of search engines and the PGFPlotsTable documentation I can't seem to tackle this rather peculiar problem, so I'd appreciate any kind of help.

## Final Solution; [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232630/24604) adapted to multi-column MWE

This is very close to the code I am using right now and is a combination of the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232630/24604) and the multi-column MWE I've given in the question.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{extarticle}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,top=2cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
        
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    Name,Number,Picture
    name1,1,
    name2,2,
    name3,3,ex1.png
    name4,4,
    name5,5,
    name6,6,
    name7,7,
    name8,8,
    name9,9,ex2.png
    name10,10,
    name11,11,
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\datatable}

\def\zz\ignorespaces#1\unskip{%
    \ifx\count#1\count
    \gdef\temp{}%
    \else
    \gdef\temp{%
        \kern.2em%
        \smash{\raisebox{-.3em}{\includegraphics[height=1.2em]{#1}}}}%
    \fi}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableset{create on use/XXX/.style={create col/set={}}}%
    
    \noindent
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
    begin table=\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth},
        end table=\end{tabularx},
    every head row/.style={output empty row,after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    columns={Picture,Name,Number,XXX,Picture,Name,Number,XXX},
    display columns/0/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{2},column type = @{}>{\zz}l@{} },
    display columns/1/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{2},column type=|l<{\temp}},
    display columns/2/.style={select equal part entry of={0}{2}},
    display columns/3/.style={column type=X|},
    display columns/4/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{2},column type = @{}>{\zz}l@{} },
    display columns/5/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{2},column type=l<{\temp}},
    display columns/6/.style={select equal part entry of={1}{2}},
    display columns/7/.style={column type=X|}
    ]{\datatable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't want to post-process the cell content, I don't think. Post-processing, as I understand it, only affects the format of the columns after the contents have been typeset. You are trying to alter the contents of the cells, so I think you need to do it earlier. This gets it to compile and gets the name etc. to show up correctly. (i.e. deleting `postproc` does this much.) Don't know about the graphics but note that I think the software expects numerical data by default.

Comment: Well, removing the `postproc` actually reverts the names to the default state; not appending the graphic paths, as I intended to do with `~\pgfplotsretval`, earlier fetching the path via `\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{Picture}\of\datatable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the image name into a table column and just pick it up within the table to typeset in the next column if not empty.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{extarticle}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,top=2cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    Name,Number,Picture
    name1,1,
    name2,2,
    name3,3,ex1.png
    name4,4,
    name5,5,
    name6,6,
    name7,7,
    name8,8,
    name9,9,ex2.png
    name10,10,
    name11,11,
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\datatable}

\def\zz\ignorespaces#1\unskip{%
\ifx\count#1\count
\gdef\temp{}%
\else
\gdef\temp{%
\kern.2em%
\smash{\raisebox{-.3em}{\includegraphics[height=1.7em]{#1}}}}%
\fi}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableset{create on use/XXX/.style={create col/set={}}}%

    \noindent
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
    begin table=\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth},
        end table=\end{tabularx},
    every head row/.style={output empty row,after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    columns={Picture,Name,Number,XXX},
    display columns/0/.style={column type = @{}>{\zz}l@{} },
    display columns/1/.style={column type = l<{\temp} },
    display columns/2/.style={column type = l },
    display columns/3/.style={column type=X|},
    ]{\datatable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! This indeed works mostly as it is supposed to, so thanks for that. I didn't even know that doing it this way is possible.  
A problem that occurs is that the images are a bit larger vertically than the lines, so they sometimes overlap with longer names. This should be easily fixable though.  
Would you mind detailing how this works? I mean, I'm glad it does, but I seem unable to grasp why. This mostly looks like TeX magic to me, most of the time I've used the `etoolbox` package for more complex statements.

Comment: @Big-Blue the image overlapping is because I made it `height=1.7em` which is probably larger than the line space then hid the height with `\smash` I used `1em` originally but then by the time the entire page shrunk to a bitmap here it hardly showed. the array column preamble `>{...}` syntax comes from the `array` package and inserts the commands into each cell. in the first column `\zz` gets the cell content as argument and then globally defines `\temp` to do nothing or insert an image, that in turn is used in the second column.